# Downgrade user from role that allows post creation

Tags: posts, user-roles, customization

I am an admin of a multi-author blog. I am implementing a monitoring system which will require me to downgrade a user from  an 'author' (this role allows them to make a custom post) back to the 'reader' role if I think it is a spam account, or if they are breaking website rules.

After changing their role using the admin screen, how can I make all the posts they made delete automatically, without having to scroll and find them myself?

Many thanks

**EDIT using advice from answers below**:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'wpse98904_remove_demoted_user_posts', 10, 2 );
function wpse98904_remove_demoted_user_posts( $demoted_author_id, $role ) {
 // In here you'd search for all the posts by the user

 $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'author' => $demoted_author_id,
            'post_type' => 'custom_post',
            // So if your custom post type is named 'xyz_book', then use:
            // 'post_type' => 'xyz_book',
 );
 $demoted_author_posts = get_posts( $args );
 foreach( $demoted_author_posts as $p ) {
     // delete the post (actually Trash it)
     if($role == 'subscriber') {
     wp_trash_post( $p->ID);
     // To force the deletion (ie, bypass the Trash):
     // wp_delete_post( $p->ID, true );
     }
 }
}
```

I used wp_trash_post to trash the events because adding 'false' to wp_delete_post did not work for me.

Comment: If you delete the user, you will have the option of removing their posts. But if you just want to demote them, then I guess that won't cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add actions to the [`set_user_role`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/set_user_role) hook:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'wpse98904_remove_demoted_user_posts', 10, 2 );
function wpse98904_remove_demoted_user_posts( $demoted_author_id, $role ) {
     if( 'subscriber' == $role ) {
         // In here you'd search for all the posts by the user
         $args = array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'author' => $demoted_author_id,
                'post_type' => '{your custom post type name}',
                // So if your custom post type is named 'xyz_book', then use:
                // 'post_type' => 'xyz_book',
         );
         $demoted_author_posts = get_posts( $args );
         foreach( $demoted_author_posts as $p ) {
             // delete the post (actually Trash it)
             wp_delete_post( $p->ID );
             // To force the deletion (ie, bypass the Trash):
             // wp_delete_post( $p->ID, true );
         }
     }
}
```

#### Reference

[`set_user_role`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/set_user_role) hook -- Codex

[`set_user_role`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L815) hook in WP Trac

[`wp_delete_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) -- Codex

Comment: Ah, just barely beat me to it. :)

Comment: @AndrewBartel Sometimes I win the race, sometimes I lose it...

Comment: @PatJ Thanks it deleted the posts as aksed. But this function applied to all users, including my fellow admins. How can i alter the function further so that this function only applies to 'Author' users.

Comment: Add in the if statement from my answer @Adzay

Comment: @Adazy I've updated my code to include Andrew Bartel's `if` statement.

Comment: @PatJ adding the conditional where you placed it didnt work for me, but I moved it. You can see it in my edited answer. However, I don't think I made what I wanted it to do clear.

Your function says  "If role is changed to Subscriber apply this function.."  What I want the function to be is "If user is Author, apply this function when the role is changed to Subscriber"

Comment: The `WP_User` class has a `remove_role()` function, but it doesn't look like `remove_role()` has any associated hooks, at least in v3.5.1.  `set_user_role` might be as close as you get.

Comment: [Codex reference for WP_User class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User)

Answer (score 1):

Users roles are changed by the WP_User object firing the set_role() function.  At the end of that function on line 815 of wp-includes/capabilities.php there is an action to hook to: `do_action( 'set_user_role', $this->ID, $role );`

So, in your functions.php or in a plugin, you can grab that data as the hook fires after the user capability update, and delete all of a user's posts with [wp_delete_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).

```
add_action('set_user_role','myfunc',10,2);
function myfunc($user_id,$role) {
    if($role == 'subscriber') { // or whatever you want
        $posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&author='.$user_id);
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            wp_delete_post($post->ID,true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, be careful, because as is, this snippet will permenently delete the post.  If you want to just move it to trash, change the second parameter or wp_delete_post to false.

Comment: Looking at [the source of the `set_user_role` hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L815), it looks like `$role` is the *new* role of the user.  If I'm reading your code right, it will delete all posts for a user who has just been changed to the Author role -- which I don't think is quite what is asked for.

Comment: Right, thus the comment.  But you're right that if copy pasted it would nuke someone's posts who was just promoted to author.  I'll edit for readability.

Comment: @PatJ Hi thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I should have added that it was a custom post type that I was trying to delete, is that why it didn't work?
I tried to add `&post_type=Custom` to `get_posts()` but still ... no luck.

Comment: I'll edit my code to take the CPT thing into account.